# iOS testing with XCTest and separate file

Tags: ios, xctest

Currently, I write my testing in 1 file (default). Is it possible to have multiple files and test?

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
}

- (void)tearDown {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testExample {
    // This is an example of a functional test case.
    XCTAssert(YES, @"Pass");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have many files and many tests per file. The first one is just the one made by Xcode automatically, but all that makes it special is that it:

1. Implements a subclass of XCTestCase
2. Is a member of the testing target (not your app target)

Making another file with the same characteristics is simple.

In Xcode, File -> New -> iOS -> Source -> UI Test Case Class

The convention is to group related tests into a source file, and then name that source file ___Tests.swift (or .m)

For example, `SharingTests.swift` might contain the methods `testSharingToFacebook()` and `testSharingToTwitter()`.